# MS SQL Create user and change pwd in user transaction

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000

I need to grant access of existing login into my database and change password of other login from a T-SQL script that is run from C++ update program in transaction. It should run against SQL Server 2000 and also against any newer SQL Server version.

`CREATE USER FOR LOGIN` and `ALTER LOGIN WITH PASSWORD` are not supported in MSDE and SQL Server 2000 but I'm not able to use `sp_grantdbaccess` and `sp_password` either because they fail with error -2147217900

That I think is caused by the fact that these stored procedures cannot be run from user transaction and it can also be deprecated in future SQL Server versions.

Can you suggest any other solution?

Below is the sample of the script that is run in user transaction

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[_PasswordChangeSaveCleanup]  
@Meno varchar(50),  
@HesloEncrypted varchar(50)  
AS  
BEGIN  
...     
return 1  
END  
GO  
--CREATE USER [some] FOR LOGIN [some]  
EXECUTE sp_grantdbaccess @loginame='some'  
GO  
GRANT SELECT ON [dbo].[UZivatelia] TO [ese]  
GO  
--ALTER LOGIN SOME2 WITH PASSWORD='vreK.BH45'  
EXECUTE sp_password @new='vreK.BH45',@loginame='SOME2'  
GO  
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[SOMESP]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))  
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[SOMESP]  
GO
```

Comment: `sp_grantdbaccess` and `sp_password` are deprecated but still supported in every version of SQL Server up to and including 2012, so you shouldn't be getting any invalid SQL errors. Can you show the complete SQL batch that throws an error? And as the documentation [states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174428.aspx), you can't use `sp_password` within a transaction anyway.

Comment: I know that they are still there but the problem is that I need to make these changes within the transaction and this is not possible for sp_password and sp_grantdbaccess.

Comment: So what exactly are you asking? Are you asking how to address the error you get, or how to use `ALTER LOGIN` inside a transaction?

Comment: No, what I'm asking is a way to grant access of an sql login to db container and change password that will run from SQL 7.0 to 2012 from within user transaction.

Comment: I think the short answer is, you can't: the only way to add a login in SQL 2000 is to use `sp_addlogin` and it cannot be used in a transaction. So you need to revisit your requirements: either you have to drop support for SQL 7/2000, or you have to drop the requirement to use a transaction. I don't know the background to your question, but SQL 7 and 2000 are both so old that there is little point in supporting them for most people. As for the transaction, if you explain why you need a transaction then someone may have an alternative approach.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. You've confirmed my suspicion. I will have to live with that (clients using old SQL versions need to be handled manually - 4 of them so not a big problem).